# UIPageViewController display hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, viewdidappear

I have a `UIPageViewController` that contains multiple view controllers (self is a subclass of `UIPageViewController`, and I just put in one view controller here to demonstrate my question):

```
ViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
[self setViewControllers:@[viewController] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If I put a log in both self and `ViewController` class, seems like the `viewDidAppear` in `ViewController` class gets called BEFORE the `viewDidAppear` in `UIPageViewController`.

The problem I have is I need to check `visibleCells` method in `collectionView` that's embedded in `ViewController` class. In this scenario, the visible cells method is returning empty array of cells (since it gets called before `UIPageViewController` is ready to show). However, everything works fine when I am not using the `UIPageViewController` as a container.

I tried `addChildViewController` to see if I have any luck but it's not working (obviously). Is there a way in `UIPageViewController` that can manage the flow of view cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page view controller has many bugs related to displaying views. Perhaps a more correct place to add your logic is `viewDidLayoutSubviews` since this will be called whenever a layout pass has occurred and the frame of the view might have changed.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much. How do I select you answer as correct answer?